# How to identify whether webp image is static or animated?

Tags: javascript, php, webp

I am working on a project where a user can upload `webp` images. I know how to convert `webp` images into jpg/png, but am stuck on how to identify whether the `webp` image is static (non-animated) or animated.

I want to identify them because I use different commands for conversion:

Command for non-animated webp to jpg:

`dwebp nonanimated.webp -o jpg.jpg`

Command for animated webp to non-animated webp (takes 2nd frame):

`webpmux -get frame 2 animated.webp -o nonanimated.webp`

But I cannot find a single command that handle both cases.

I am using PHP on the server side, and HTML and Javascript for frontend.

Comment: As far as I know it's only GIF that can animate

Comment: If ^^ is correct you can use this code from php manual https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php#59787

Comment: This code only checks `gif` not `webp`. `Webp` also can animate, Please check this using Chrome Browser http://cloudinary.com/blog/animated_webp_how_to_convert_animated_gif_to_webp_and_save_up_to_90_bandwidth

Comment: Can you not check if the file has frames? If it has more than 1 then treat as animated else it must be static...

Comment: How can i check?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a lot of investigation i found that animated `webp` images always conatins some string, when open in a text editor and non animated images doesn't. The strings are `ANMF` and `ANIM`. I checked these string in all webp images which i have. So this is perfect for me. Here are some solutions in `PHP`, `Javascript` and `Shell Script`:

In PHP:

```
<?php
function isWebpAnimated($src){
    $webpContents = file_get_contents($src);
    $where = strpos($webpContents, "ANMF");
    if ($where !== FALSE){
        // animated
        $isAnimated = true;
    }
    else{
        // non animated
        $isAnimated = false;
    }
    return $isAnimated;
}
?>
```

In Javascript:

```
function isWebpAnimated(src) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', src, true);
    request.addEventListener('load', function () {
        if(request.response.indexOf("ANMF") != -1){
            // animated
            alert(true);
        }
        else{
            // non animated
            alert(false);
        }
    });
    request.send();
}
```

But In case of large images `PHP` and `Javascript` not working well, So best Solution is to use `Shell Script`, If you have `Ubuntu`.

In Shell Script:

```
echo $(grep -c "ANMF" ~/animated.webp)
```

return 0 if non animated, else non zero value for animated.

EDIT: In Python

```py
def isWebpAnimated(src):
    try:
        with open(src, 'rb') as f:
            data = f.read()

        # Check if the file starts with 'RIFF' and contains 'WEBPVP8' or 'WEBPVP8X'
        # if data.startswith(b'RIFF') and (b'WEBPVP8' in data or b'WEBPVP8X' in data):

        # Now will chk a byte b"ANMF" in file data
        if b"ANMF" in data:
            # The 'ANIM' indicating that the given file is Animated
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    except Exception as err:
        exit(f"Error Occure: {err}")
```

Comment: Note that this solution will produce false-positives in rare cases when some bytes in the file happen to contain the same binary values as the string "ANMF". Parsing the webp header as suggested in the other answers would be more reliable.

Comment: Also it would work equally fast for files of any size, since you only need to read a few bytes at the very beginning of the file.

Comment: In PHP, the `if`, `else` and `return` blocks can be replaced by `return ($where !== FALSE);`.

Comment: The Python version returns 1 for non-animated webp images, too. Did someone experience this two?

Comment: @CoffeeToCodette you are correct, I updated the code, please check now

Comment: Yes, that's working. Thank you. I also added "or b'ANIM' in data". Just to be sure.

Answer (score 7):

There are flags in Webp header, ANIMATION among others. Small function to check it:

```
function isWebpAnimated($fn){
  $result = false;
  $fh = fopen($fn, "rb"); 
  fseek($fh, 12);
  if(fread($fh, 4) === 'VP8X'){
    fseek($fh, 16);
    $myByte = fread($fh, 1);
    $result = ((ord($myByte) >> 1) & 1)?true:false;
  }
  fclose($fh);
  return $result;
}
```

ANIM and ANMF are from next chunk headers.

[RIFF container specification](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/riff_container)

Comment: `?true:false` can be removed, it's not necessary to change a boolean to a boolean.

Answer (score 5):

According [Sven Liivak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10299681/sven-liivak)'s `isWebpAnimated()`... there is a small bug.

`fseek($fh, 16);`

should be:

`fseek($fh, 20);`

Because postion `16` is the `chunk_size` position in `VP8X`.
But we need the `flag` position which is at `20`.

Fixed function:

```php
function isWebpAnimated($fn){
  $result = false;
  $fh = fopen($fn, "rb"); 
  fseek($fh, 12);
  if(fread($fh, 4) === 'VP8X'){
    fseek($fh, 20);
    $myByte = fread($fh, 1);
    $result = ((ord($myByte) >> 1) & 1)?true:false;
  }
  fclose($fh);
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer. the other one always returns true for any webp

Answer (score 2):

This is my java code, it works for me.

```
static boolean isWebpAnimated(InputStream in) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            in.skip(12);
            byte[] buf = new byte[4];
            int i = in.read(buf);
            if ("VP8X".equals(new String(buf, 0, i))) {
                in.skip(12);
                result = (in.read(buf) == 4 && (buf[3] & 0x00000002) != 0);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: some webp contains VP8L

Comment: I had extracted frames from webp and those static frames are detected as animated according to this function. I think we should also check for ANIM header

Answer (score 2):

Fixing @ccomangee's solution.
Some static webp images would be detected as animated and can cause issue in the application.

I had extracted webp frames and saved as webp images and tried to identify by checking VP8X signature and it exists in given position although It is static image.  So if there is VP8X it does not mean that the image would be animated having more than one frames.

I tried few images with my solution and the result is below:

```
                             riff   webp  vp8*   anim
OK(anim-trans).webp:      [ RIFF | WEBP | VP8X | ANIM ]
Cuppy(static-trans).webp: [ RIFF | WEBP | VP8L | NA?  ]
glass(anim-solid).webp:   [ RIFF | WEBP | VP8X | ANIM ]
sunset(anim-trans).webp:  [ RIFF | WEBP | VP8X | ANIM ]
atom(anim_solid).webp:    [ RIFF | WEBP | VP8X | ANIM ]
spread(anim-trans).webp:  [ RIFF | WEBP | VP8X | ANIM ]
heart(static-trans).webp: [ RIFF | WEBP | VP8X | NA?  ] 
ludo(static-trans).webp:  [ RIFF | WEBP | VP8X | NA?  ]
scene(static_solid).webp: [ RIFF | WEBP | VP8  | NA?  ]
```

Here all images are named according to its type.
anim-trans: animated image contains transparency (alpha channel support)
anim-solid: animated image having no transparency
static-trans and static-solid are static images.

VP8L is loseless webp and VP8X contains extended features.
VP8 is surely static image.

If VP8X exists it could be static or animated most images would be animated.

The solution is

Read 4 bytes -> 'RIFF'
Skip 4 bytes
Read 4 bytes -> 'WEBP'
Read 4 bytes -> 'VP8X' / 'VP8L' / 'VP8'
skip 14 bytes
Read 4 bytes -> 'ANIM'

Java Code:

```java
 public static boolean check(File file) {
            boolean riff = false;
            boolean webp = false;
            boolean vp8x = false;
            boolean anim = false;
        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file)) {

            byte[] buf = new byte[4];
            int i = in.read(buf); // 4
            
            if(buf[0] == 0x52 && buf[1] == 0x49 && buf[2]==0x46 && buf[3] == buf[2] )
                riff = true;

            in.skip(4); // ???? (8+)
            i = in.read(buf); // (12+)
            if(buf[0] == 0x57 && buf[1] == 0x45 && buf[2]==0x42 && buf[3] == 0x50 )
                    webp = true   ;             

            i = in.read(buf); // (16+)
            if(buf[0] == 0x41 && buf[1] == 0x4e && buf[2]==0x49 && buf[3] == 0x4d );
                vp8x = true;
                
            in.skip(14); // then next 4 should contain ANIM - 41 4e 49 4d
            i = in.read(buf);
            if(buf[0] == 0x41 && buf[1] == 0x4e && buf[2]==0x49 && buf[3] == 0x4d )
                anim = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("errrrrr "+e.getMessage());
        }
        return riff && webp && anim;

    }
```

you can directly read WEBP by skipping 8 bytes then count and skipp all chunks before ANIM and read that position if ANIM exist then its animated webp image else static.

File layout of webp images
https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/riff_container#example_file_layouts

Ref: Google WEBP specification https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/riff_container

Answer (score 2):

I apologize for joining this discussion late, but I'm also seeking a Python-based solution for offline use.

Although I'm not well-versed in PHP or JavaScript, I do have some knowledge of Python. Here's what I've discovered: you can determine whether a WebP image is an animation or a static image using the Python Imaging Library (PIL).

To count the number of frames in a WebP image and identify animations, you can utilize PIL's `Image` and `ImageSequence` modules. Here's a Python script to accomplish this:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageSequence

def is_animation(file):
    image = Image.open(file)
    count = 0
    for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(image):
        count += 1
    return count > 1
```

By using this code, you can call the `is_animation` function, passing the file path as an argument. If the image contains more than one frame, the function will return `True`, indicating that it's an animation; otherwise, it will return `False` for a static image.

Comment: PIL (or Pillow) has `is_animated` attribute for this purpose. See https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.is_animated

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_webp_animation(img_content):
    # https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/riff_container#extended_file_format
    # webp Animation image.
    return len(img_content) > 20 and img_content[0:4] == b'RIFF' and img_content[8:12] == b'WEBP' \
            and img_content[12:16] == b'VP8X' \
            and int.from_bytes(img_content[20:21], 'little') & 2 == 2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution in BASH (Linux). Work in Debian 12 without any needed softwares added. Search and COPY animated webp files to desktop. It is easy to modify my script to accommodate your need. Some idea come from here.

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$(zenity  --file-selection --filename=$HOME/ --title="Choose a directory to convert all file" --directory)
rm "/dev/shm/findaniwebp.txt" 2> /dev/null
rm "/dev/shm/findfiles.txt" 2> /dev/null
find "$file" -iname '*.webp' >> "/dev/shm/findfiles.txt" 2>/dev/null

{
result=0
input="/dev/shm/findfiles.txt"
while IFS= read -r "line"
do
result=$(echo $(grep -c "ANMF" "$line"))
if [ "$result" -ge 10 ]; then
echo "Animated webp is found !"
echo $line
echo $line >> "/dev/shm/findaniwebp.txt"
fi
done < "$input"
}

if [ ! -f "/dev/shm/findaniwebp.txt" ]
then
aniwebp=0
else
aniwebp=$(wc -l < "/dev/shm/findaniwebp.txt")
echo "Finding finish (webp only) , with file to move : $aniwebp"
fi

if [ "$aniwebp" -ge "1" ]; then
if zenity --no-wrap --question --text="Do you want to COPY theseS fileS to $HOME/Desktop ?"
then
{
input="/dev/shm/findaniwebp.txt"
while IFS= read -r "line"
do
cp "$line" "$HOME"/Desktop
echo file moved...
done < "$input"
}
fi
else
echo "NO animated webp found!"
fi

rm "/dev/shm/findaniwebp.txt" 2> /dev/null
rm "/dev/shm/findfiles.txt" 2> /dev/null
read -n 1 -s -r -p "Press ENTER key to exit !"
exit
```