# Animated webp not playing on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, html5-canvas, webp

Tried implementation an animated webp on canvas and its only taking the first frame.
https://codepen.io/Rajdeepc/pen/MWEyRqR

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'https://i.giphy.com/media/ftAP63cOawNMdjc3Zo/giphy.webp';
```

Comment: That is correct. The `drawImage` command does not look at animation frames. I solve this kind of problem by opening the image in an image editor and export each frame separately.

Comment: My use case is to play that animated webp on a html5 canvas and people can draw also on top of that.It is a drawing app I am trying to build

Comment: You can put all the animation frames next to each other, and build a spritesheet animation. You can find example code for spritesheets online. Some libraries like PixiJS support it too.

Comment: Yes this is the correct approach. But there is no support to extract frames from webp file types.

Comment: Not in canvas, but you can use an image editor like Photoshop or an online editor, and extract the individual frames.

Comment: From what I read you can check if the webp source file contains the word "ANIM", but then you'll have to parse it yourself... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45190469/how-to-identify-whether-webp-image-is-static-or-animated